# How to submit multiple table rows inside a form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter, ajaxform

I know this is not going to work. But this is what I am trying to do. I want multiple table rows data to be submitted to the form action not all at a once, but when clicking on the individual rows. Not sure how to make it work!

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

    <?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/manageAdv',array('id'=>'manageAdv'))?>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered tablesorter advTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>New Image</th>
                <th>Alternate Text</th>
                <th>Link</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($content as $row):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $counter = $counter+1;?></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['title']?>" name="title"></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['file_name']?></td>
                <td><input type="file" class="form-control" name="upload"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['alt']?>" name="alt"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['link']?>" name="link"></td>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" name="id">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['file_path']?>" name="path">
                <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="update">Update</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="delete">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php form_close()?>
</div>
```

Comment: seeing as you tagged it jquery & ajaxform, you know that javascript is required for this, so are you asking for code?

Comment: yes. It would be great if you could share me some code snippet.

Comment: You can use simple javascript and ajax to get it working. Clarify more on what you want when clicking the rows (which rows) and what you want to happen. This is not difficult, very easy to get working

Comment: @Rattansingh Ok.. I want the details to be displayed in the form of a table. So when the user clicks on the update button the form values should be passed with respect to the particular row. If this can be done, then I can handle the delete with just an id.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by putting a checkbox with the value of `id` in your form for each data entry:

```
<?php foreach ($content as $row):?>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" name="id[]"></td>
    <td><?php echo $counter = $counter+1;?></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['title']?>" name="title[]"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['file_name']?></td>
    <td><input type="file" class="form-control" name="upload[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['alt']?>" name="alt[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['link']?>" name="link[]"></td>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['file_path']?>" name="path">
    <td>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="update">Update</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="delete">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Then when the form is submitted, you can have a loop that manipulates each data entry based on whether the checkbox was checked or not.

Here's an example:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST[alt]); $i++) {
    if(isset($_POST[$i][id])) {
        // do something with $_POST[$i][id]
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Keep the number of rows in a hidden field, on the top of the form.

```
    <input type="hidden"  value="<?php count($content); ?>" name="row_count"/>
```

Use a unique name for input fields and submit buttons in each row, for eg, use a variable $i which is incremented on each loop.

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['link']?>" name="link<?php echo $i; ?>"/>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="update">Update</button>
```

In contoller:

```
    if(isset($_POST)){
      $row_count=$_POST{'row_count'];

       for($i=0; $i<$row_count; $i++) {
         if(isset($_POST['submit_'.$i])) {

           // do something with $_POST['submit_'.$i]

         }
       }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.